# Relationship between input and output sequence in Hartley transformation

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, orthornormal

As you know that Discrete Hartley transformation is related to the discrete Fourier transformation, $i.e$, assuming we have a vector $X = [x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_N]$, its Hartley transformation is equal to $H(X) = Real(FFT(X)) - Imag(FFT(X))$. where $H$ denotes the Hartley transformation.

I wonder, if I want the output of the Hartley transformation equals to a vector of length $N$ whose all elements are $1$, it means $H(X) = [1,1,\ldots,1] $, what supposed to be the input $X$? I means I need to formulate the relationship between the inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia's [entry for the discrete Hartley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform) <s>shows</s> states that the $\mathsf{DHT}$ is, up to a scaling, its own inverse. If $x$ is a vector with $N$ entries and $y$ is its discrete Hartley transform,
\begin{equation}
y = \mathsf{DHT}x,
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{1}{N}\mathsf{DHT}y.
\end{equation}

---

If $x$ is a vector with $N$ entries such that
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{DHT}x = \underbrace{(1,1,\ldots,1)^{\mathsf{T}}}_{\textrm{$N$ entries}},
\end{equation}
then we recover $x$ with
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{1}{N}\mathsf{DHT}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
This means that $x$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x &=~ \frac{1}{N}\left(\mathsf{Re}\left[\mathsf{DFT}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right)\right] - \mathsf{Im}\left[\mathsf{DFT}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right)\right]\right),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\mathsf{DFT}$ is the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which we usually compute with a FFT algorithm. The $\ell^{\textrm{th}}$ entry of the $\mathsf{DFT}$ of the all-1 vector is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}1\times e^{-2\pi j \ell n/N}
&=~ 1 + e^{-2\pi j \ell/N} + \left(e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}\right)^{N-1}\\
&=~ \left\{\begin{array}{rl}N & \textrm{if}~\ell=0,\\0&\textrm{if}~\ell\neq 0.\end{array}\right.\\
&=~ N\delta_{\ell,0},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\delta_{p,q}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). One way to show this is to note that if $\ell = 0$, then each exponent is $0$, so each term in the sum is $1$. On the other hand, if $\ell\neq 0$, then $\exp(-2\pi j\ell/N) \neq 1$,and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1 + e^{-2\pi j \ell/N} + \left(e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}\right)^{N-1}
&=~ \frac{1 - \left(e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}\right)^N}{1 - e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}}\\
&=~ \frac{1 - e^{-2N\pi j \ell/N}}{1 - e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}}\\
&=~ \frac{1 - 1}{1 - e^{-2\pi j \ell/N}} ~=~ 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}


That shows that the $\mathsf{DFT}$ of the all-1 vector has no imaginary part, and its real part is $(N,0,0,\ldots,0)^{\mathsf{T}}$. Hence
\begin{equation}
x ~=~ \frac{1}{N}\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0
\end{array}\right)
~=~ \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much .. that's really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again, that's really interesting. I am trying to understand it well, if I got a question, I will let you know.

Comment: I added my question into the below answer, could you please check it .  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Hartley transform is an involution: it is (up to a scale factor) its own inverse. The classical discrete  Hartley transform of order $N$ is such that $H_N^{-1} = \frac{1}{N}H_N$. Be careful with your notation, the vector $x$ has $N+1$ entries, so maybe you are after an $N+1$-order DHT!

If $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the all-ones vector, then in matrix-vector product $H_Nx = \mathbf{1} $ is equivalent to $H_N^{-1}H_Nx = H_N^{-1}\mathbf{1} $, and you get more directly the mysterious $X$:

$$x =  \frac{1}{N}H_N\mathbf{1} $$

and you get the result given by Joe Mac by a direct computation. A little interpretation: the discrete "Dirac" signal at the origin yields a flat "Hartley" spectrum, just like for Fourier.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, I got it now. but I was wondering what's about if $H_Nx = y$ and only some values of, i.e.,  $y_{1:4:N} = 1$ and other values of $y$ are any random values. So, can we express the relationship between the $y_{1:4:N}$ and $x_{1:4:N}$  mathematically in similar way too?

Comment: I should add something, ..  So, can we express the relationship between the $y_{1:4:N}$ and $x_{1:4:N}$ OR between $y_{1:4:N}$ and $x$  mathematically in similar way too?

Comment: I don't really understand this comment. This may require a different question. But you can indeed  interleave transforms and downsampling operators, and solutions can be quite complicated

Comment: OK .. I posted it as a new question here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67696/relationship-of-input-outputs-in-hartley-transformation-based-on-few-elements-in  .. thank you

Comment: And you did well. I am not able to see a clear answer right now