# Relationship of input-outputs in Hartley transformation based on few elements in a vector

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, orthornormal

This question is related also to that question [HERE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67655/relationship-between-input-and-output-sequence-in-hartley-transformation/67682?noredirect=1#comment137674_67682), but with further details and another issue I need to solve.

Assuming we have a vector $X = [x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_N]$, its Hartley transformation is equal to $H(X) = \Re(FFT(X)) - \Im(FFT(X))$. where $H$ denotes the Hartley transformation, and $FFT$ is the discrete Fourier transformation. Which means that $y = H(X)$. My question : Is it possible to fix some values in the vector $X$, for example,  $X_{1:4:N}$ to be any values in order to have their correspondent values $y_{1:4:N}$ equal to  $[1,1,\ldots,1]?$. What supposed to be the valued of  $X_{1:4:N}$ to have the results of $y_{1:4:N}=[1,1,\ldots,1]?$

$NP:$ The values in both vectors $x$ and $y$ in the other index of $1:4:N$ are random data.

Comment: Since each entry in the input makes some contribution to each entry in the output, I don't think there is a clean relationship of the kind that I suspect you want. That is, one needs _very_ specific cancellations to guarantee 1s in specific entries of the output. There might be some special values of _N_ that have some simpler relations. What kinds of _N_ are under consideration?

Comment: @JoeMac Thank you for you comment,  $N = 1024$ is under consideration. Second, you said "There might be some special values of $N$ that have some simpler relations." Which $N$ have simpler relations?

Comment: For _N_ = 1024, for example, if **x** = (1,0,0,0,...) with that pattern repeated 1024/4 = 256 times, and if **y** = DHT**x**, then **y** is almost all 0, except (with MATLAB indexing) y(1) = y(257) = y(513) = y(769) = 256.

Comment: @JoeMac what you mean by **x = (1,0,0....)** is it all the vector $X$ of size $N$ or the vector of size 256 representing $X_{1:4:N}?$